# UIView not animating constraint change

Tags: objective-c, animation

I have a question regarding the UIView method:

```
+ (void)animateWithDuration:(NSTimeInterval)duration
             animations:(void (^)(void))animations
             completion:(void (^)(BOOL finished))completion
```

Basically I am just trying to set a height constraints constant to 0 and have the change look like its slowly shrinking...

My Code looks like this:

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:0.7
                     animations:^{
                         //hide the Title
                         self.titleCellHeigthConstraint.constant = kLabelHeightZero;
                         [self.contentView layoutIfNeeded];
                     }

                     completion:nil];
```

Unfortunately it's not animating. It simply makes all changes appear with a little delay (which might be the 0.7 seconds specified in the method).

Now my question is if there is any way to get the UIView to animate the change?

Thanks in Advance!

**Edit:**

The weird thing is if I reverse the changes in an animated fashion it does it exactly the way I want it. The code I'am using for that is:

```
//animate layout changes
    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.7
                     animations:^{
                         //hide activity indicator and label
                         [self.activityIndicator stopAnimating];
                         [self.label setHidden:YES];
                     }

                     completion:^(BOOL arg0){
                         [UIView animateWithDuration:0.3
                                          animations:^{
                                              //show title label
                                              self.titleCellHeigthConstraint.constant = kDefaultLabelHeight;
                                              [self.contentView layoutIfNeeded];
                                          }];
                     }];
```

Comment: Are you sure that your code is executing on the main thread, and not an asynchronous background thread?

Comment: Yes I am sure, to test I've put the code into a dispatch block:

Comment: 'dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{/*animations*/});'

Comment: As an experiment, put your entire animation call in a dispatch_main_queue. Furthermore, adjust your label's alpha channel rather than the hidden property (only certain specific properties can be animated). Let me know how that goes!

Answer (score 0):

You want to change the properties of the UIView not the NSLayoutConstraint in the animation method. I.e. Change the layout constraint's constant before the UIView method and then change the UIView's frame property in the animation method.

This way you won't need to call layoutIfNeeded.

Comment: Sorry but thats not what I am looking for. When using Autolayout you're not supposed to set the UIViews frame Property directly, instead you modify the constraints attached to the view and let the auto layout engine figure out the frame - which is exactly what I'm doing, setting frames is part of the "old" springs and struts system...